# Override Cordova Log

Tags: java, android, cordova

I need to override the Log in Cordova Plugin because the code I'm using has some other functions i.e. Log.info which are causing a load of errors

In the code I'm using they override as such

```
 public class GridActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize YiCameraPlatform
    try {
        Platform.initialize(new Logger() {
            @Override
            public void verbose(String message) {
                Log.v("YiCameraPlatform", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void info(String message) {
                Log.i("YiCameraPlatform", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void warning(String message) {
                Log.w("YiCameraPlatform", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void error(String message) {
                Log.e("YiCameraPlatform", message);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

I need to do something similar in the plugin initialiser

```
public class XiaomiYiCordovaPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
   super.initialize(cordova, webView);
```

Can anyone let me know how to do this?

I'm trying things such as

```
 Log = new Logger() {
@Override
public void verbose(String message) {
  Log.v("YiCameraPlatform", message);
}

@Override
public void info(String message) {
  Log.i("YiCameraPlatform", message);
}

@Override
public void warning(String message) {
  Log.w("YiCameraPlatform", message);
}

@Override
public void error(String message) {
  Log.e("YiCameraPlatform", message);
}
```

};

To no avail..

Comment: What's up in Logger.java, specificaly in line 44?

Comment: I think you'd better off posting your own code and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I've changed what I'm trying to get hold off..